# Validate Mobile number using regular expression

Tags: regex

I need to validate mobile number. My need:

> 1. The number may start with +8801 or 8801 or 01
> 2. The next number can be 1 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9
> 3. Then there have exact 8 digit.

How can i write the regular expression using this conditions ?

the mobile numbers I tried

```
+8801811419556
01811419556
8801711419556
01611419556
8801511419556
```

Comment: Update your question with your code what you tried already.

Comment: 8 digit mobile number???

Comment: A word of caution - regular expressions often aren't the easiest things to read even for seasoned programmers. Ask yourself the question: If the criteria changed, would you be comfortable making further changes?

Comment: @Shurmajee Actually the number is 11 digit long. All number start with 01. Then next 1 digit varies from operator to operator. Then the next 8 digit provided by operator.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Should be pretty simple:

```
^(?:\+?88)?01[15-9]\d{8}$
```

- `^` - From start of the string
- `(?:\+?88)?` - optional `88`, which *may* begin in `+`
- `01` - mandatory `01`
- `[15-9]` - "1 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9"
- `\d{8}` -  8 digits
- `$` - end of the string

Working example: http://rubular.com/r/BvnSXDOYF8

**Update 2020**

As BTRC approved 2 new prefixes, 013 for Grameenphone and 014 for Banglalink, updated expression for now:

```
^(?:\+?88)?01[13-9]\d{8}$
```

Comment: Yeah, yours looks better :)

Comment: 008801812596824 This mobile number is valid or not by using your example
Please check and reply me using your given link
http://rubular.com/r/BvnSXDOYF8

Comment: @MajbahHabib - The question does not ask for numbers starting with `00`, so no. You can relatively easily change the pattern, for example, assuming `00` is an international access code: `^(?:(?:\+|00)?88)?01[15-9]\d{8}$`

Answer (score 3):

**You may use either one of given regular expression to validate Bangladeshi mobile number.**

**Solution 1:**

```
/(^(\+88|0088)?(01){1}[56789]{1}(\d){8})$/
```

Robi, Grameen Phone, Banglalink, Airtel and Teletalk operator mobile no are allowed.

**Solution 2:**

```
 /(^(\+8801|8801|01|008801))[1|5-9]{1}(\d){8}$/
```

Citycell, Robi, Grameen Phone, Banglalink, Airtel and Teletalk operator mobile no are allowed.

Allowed mobile number pattern

+8801812598624

008801812598624

01812598624

01712598624

01919598624

01672598624

01512598624

**................**

**.................**

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regular expression and test  it if you want on following site quickly

[regex pal](http://regexpal.com/)

[8]*01[15-9]\d{8}

Answer (score 1):

I know, that question was asked long time ago, but i assume that @G. M. Nazmul Hossain want to validate mobile number againt chosen country. I show you, how to do it with free library [libphonenumber from Google](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber). It's available for Java, C++ and Javascript, but there're also fork for PHP and, i believe, other languages.

+880 tells me that it's [country code for Bangladesh](http://www.countrycallingcodes.com/country.php?country=Bangladesh). Let's try to validate example numbers with following code in Javascript:

```
String bdNumberStr = "8801711419556"
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
    //BD is default country code for Bangladesh (used for number without 880 at the begginning)
    PhoneNumber bdNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(bdNumberStr, "BD");
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
    System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
boolean isValid = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(bdNumberProto); // returns true
```

That code will handle also numbers with spaces in it (for example "880 17 11 41 95 56"), or even with 00880 at the beggininng (+ is sometimes replaced with 00).

Try it out yourself on [demo page](http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo-compiled.html). Validates all of provided examples and even more.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
This is nice but it shows 
"8801311419556" and "8801411419556"
as valid number
But these two format are invalid mobile number.

Comment: @G. M. Nazmul Hossain - Are you sure, they aren't valid? You can fill bug on libphonenumber page for it: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/issues . Google's building DB all over the world, so they would've missed something ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at libphonenumber at:
https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Answer (score 0):

> Bangladeshi phone number (*Citycell*, *Robi*, *Grameen Phone*, *Banglalink*, *Airtel* and *Teletalk* **operators**) validation by using regular expression :

```
$pattern = '/(^(\+8801|8801|01|008801))[1-9]{1}(\d){8}$/';
$BangladeshiPhoneNo = "+8801840001417";

if(preg_match($pattern, $BangladeshiPhoneNo)){
    echo "It is a valid Bangladeshi phone number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Laravel Bangladeshi Phone No validation for (Citycell, Robi, Grameen Phone, Banglalink, Airtel and Teletalk) and start with +88/88 then 01 then 356789 then 8 digit**  



public function rules()
        {
            return [

                'mobile' => 'sometimes|regex:/^(?:\+?88)?01[35-9]\d{8}$/',

            ];
        }

        public function messages()
        {

                'mobile.regex' => 'Mobile no should be bd standard',
            ];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying ([^(?:+?88)?01[13-9]\d{8}$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088518/validate-mobile-number-using-regular-expression/15088746#15088746)),
my program shows the correct

> 8801100001111

---

> 1. The number may start with +8801 or 8801 or 01.***(I want only 8801)***.
> 2. The next number can be 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 which are valid number in the position for Bangladesh.
> 3. Then there have exact 8 digit.

my solution ==> `^8801[3-9]\d{8}$`

Regular expression of Bangladeshi phone numbers(what i want) where
**number of characters=13** , **start with `8801`**, the **5th character can be `3 to 9` not `0, 1, 2`**, and the other **8 characters can be `0 to 9`**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).