# Regular expression for validating a mobile number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using regular expressions to validate mobile numbers in Javascript.

My conditions are:

1. The mobile number may start with +60 or +63 or +62 or +66 or 0
2. The mobile number have a length between 9 to 13

I have tried with the code:

```
^(?:\+60|+63|+62|+66|0)[. ()-]*(?:\d[. ()-]*){10,11,12,13}$/;
```

But I didn't get it.

The example mobile numbers are

```
+601126314441
01126342542
+631124445675
+661124445675
+621124445675
+60111243236
+62105273214
0105273214
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088518/validate-mobile-number-using-regular-expression

Comment: Can you post an example of a number that should be matched, but isn't ? Or an example of a number that isn't matched, but should be?

Comment: Upated the Mobile numbers..@Guntram Blohm

Comment: @PravinKumar only this conditions? or something else like brackets?

Comment: Only conditions..@Grundy

Comment: so try this `/(\+60|\+63|\+62|\+66|0)\d{9,13}/`

Comment: @Grundy: here Minimum 9 characters doesn't satisfy..

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/Cs3ofsO3Pe Here I have tried @Grundy

Comment: @Grundy Sry..Thanks i got it... It was my mistake.. I put there 8 insted of 9..

Comment: @PravinKumar got you a working version in JS if you'd like

Comment: @Deryck Sure.. but my length includes whole mobile number length including the prefix as +60,0,+66 like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var testCases = [
    '+601126314441',
    '01126342542',
    '+631124445675',
    '+661124445675',
    '+621124445675',
    '+60111243236',
    '+62105273214',
    '0105273214'
]

function testMobNum (nstr) {
    return /^((\+{1}(60|62|63|66){1})|(0)){1}\d{9,13}$/.test(nstr);
}

testCases.map(testMobNum);
//returns [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your RegEx like so:

```
/^(\+60|\+63|\+62|\+66|0)\d{9,13}$/gm
```

Verify at www.jsregex.com (don't forget to check the global and multiline options)

### [Fiddle Example :)](http://jsfiddle.net/6GsQL/)

### Javascript:

```
var reg = /(\+60|\+63|\+62|\+66|0)\d{9,13}/m;
var numbers = ['+601126314441', '01126342542', '+631124445675', '+661124445675', '+621124445675', '+60111243236', '+62105273214', '0105273214'];
var matched = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (reg.test(numbers[i])) matched.push(numbers[i]);
}
console.log(matched.toString());
```

Comment: With this regexp, the matched number will have between 11 and 15 numbers in it if it begins with +6[0236] and between 10 and 14 numbers if it begins with 0. You should modify the \d{9,13} part.

Comment: @Valentin possibly code length not included for mobile length

Comment: @Grundy Requirements aren't clear enough to be sure, that's true :)

Comment: Yeah I just went by what his original number was I'm sure he can tweak it to figure the correct numbers.  Unfortunately I know nothing about these phone number assignments haha

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp from this example -

```
$a = array(
'+601126314441',
'01126342542',
'+631124445675',
'+6611244-45675',
'+621124445675',
'+60111243236',
'+62105273214',
'01052-73214',
);

foreach($a as &$phone) {
    echo $phone . ' -> ';
    if (preg_match('/^(?:\+60|\+63|\+62|\+66|0)[0-9-]{9,13}$/', $phone)) {
        echo 'PASS';
    } else {
        echo 'FAIL';
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

In php this will outputs following:

```
+601126314441 -> PASS
01126342542 -> PASS
+631124445675 -> PASS
+6611244-45675 -> PASS
+621124445675 -> PASS
+60111243236 -> PASS
+62105273214 -> PASS
01052-73214 -> PASS
```

Answer (score 0):

if code length include to full mobile number you can try

```
/^(\+6[0236]\d{7,11})|(0\d{8,12})$/
```

if `+` also include in number length then

```
/^(\+6[0236]\d{6,10})|(0\d{8,12})$/
```

else try

```
/^(\+6[0236]|0)\d{9,13}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm interesting :)

**Java Script Code:**

```
// your regex pattern to check mobile number
var mobRegex = /^(\+60|\+63|\+62|\+66|0)\d{9,13}$/;
// empty array
var validMobile = [];
// some sample numbers to check
var mobileCollection = [
    '+60123456789',
    '+691234567891',
    '+6012345678912',
    '+60123456789123',
    '+601234567891234',
    '+63123456789',
    '+631WE234567891',
    '+6312345678912',
    '+63123456789123',
    '+6312 34567891234',
    '+62123456789',
    '+621234567891',
    '+6212345678912',
    '+62123456789123',
    '+6212-34567891234',
    '+66123456789',
    '+661234567891',
    '+6612345678912',
    '+66123456789123',
    '+661234OP7891234',
    '0123456789',
    '01234567891',
    '+9112445678912',
    '0123456789123',
    '01234567891234'
];
// check every number and file right one
for (var i = 0; i < mobileCollection.length; i++) {
    if (mobRegex.test(mobileCollection[i])) {
        validMobile.push(mobileCollection[i]);
    }
}
// alert all valid mobile number
alert(validMobile.toString());
// here is output
+60123456789,+6012345678912,+60123456789123,+601234567891234,+63123456789,
+6312345678912,+63123456789123,+62123456789,+621234567891,+6212345678912,
+62123456789123,+66123456789,+661234567891,+6612345678912,+66123456789123,
0123456789,01234567891,0123456789123,01234567891234
```